# list to string in df.to-csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which includes a column that has a list. When I write the dataframe to a file then re-open it, I end up converting the list to a string. Is there a way to safely read/write dataframes that have lists as members?

```
df1 = DataFrame({'a':[['john quincy', 'tom jones', 'jerry rice'],['bob smith','sally ride','little wayne'],['seven','eight','nine'],['ten','eleven','twelve']],'b':[9,2,4,5], 'c': [7,3,0,9]})

df1.to_csv('temp.csv')
df2 = read_csv('temp.csv')

#note how the list (df1) has been converted to a string (df2)
df1['a'][0]
['john quincy', 'tom jones', 'jerry rice']

df2['a'][0]
"['john quincy', 'tom jones', 'jerry rice']"
```

Comment: After reading in don't you want the reverse? `lambda L: L.split(',')` - not join again...

Comment: i put that in to show that it has been converted to  a string. It was just illustrating the case. if you open the tempfile you will see that the list column has quotes around it.

Comment: submitted an issue on pandas github https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to covert the list into string in the first place, list's will be converted to string automatically. Just write the dataframe containing a list, and use `ast.literal_eval` on `df2`

```
                                             a  b  c
0   ['john quincy', 'tom jones', 'jerry rice']  9  7
1  ['bob smith', 'sally ride', 'little wayne']  2  3
2                   ['seven', 'eight', 'nine']  4  0
3                  ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve']  5  9

df1.to_csv('temp.csv')
df2 = read_csv('temp.csv')
```

Use `ast.literal_eval` to get the string back to list:

```
import ast
fd2['a']=df2['a'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
type(df2['a'][1])
```

Output:

```
list
```

Comment: root, thanks for your input. The string conversion part was misleading. I want to do that as part of my script but I was getting an error because although I expected a list I returned as string.

Comment: @ root. Your answer works great. I rewrote the question for clarity. Although I would prefer if the pandas read/write parsers would recognize this automatically.

Comment: Note: you can do this without the lambda: just do `.apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
df2['a'] =df2['a'].map(f)
                   ^^^^^^
```

Where `f = lambda x : ','.join(x)`

There's no point joining it again, you want to split it to a list:

```
df2['a'] = df2['a'].map(lambda L: L.split(','))
```

Comment: I rewrote the answer to remove the map function as it was more confusing than helpful. thank you for your answer